# How to check best-attending employees of the year

Tags: php, mysql, time-and-attendance

This is my MySQL table:

```
_______________________________________________
Id | Name| Employee id | Date       | Attendance
_______________________________________________
1  | xyz |     196     | 2013-04-01 | present  
2  | xyz |     196     | 2013-04-02 | present  
3  | xyz |     196     | 2013-04-03 | present  
4  | xyz |     196     | 2013-04-04 | absent  
5  | xyz |     196     | 2013-04-05 | present  
6  | abc |     197     | 2013-04-01 | present

7  | abc |     197     | 2013-04-02 | present  
8  | abc |     197     | 2013-04-03 | present  
9  | abc |     197     | 2013-04-04 | present  
10 | abc |     197     | 2013-04-05 | present

_______________________________________________
```

I want to count a days who employee are mostly present, and I want like this result in PHP:

```
___________________________________________________________
 Name| Employee id| Attendance     | Best OR NOT
___________________________________________________________
 xyz |  196       | 4 Present days |

 abc |  197       | 5 Present days | This is best employees of the year

__________________________________________________________________________
```

How can i do this?

Comment: So you're the best employee because you were lucky enough to not get sick/worst period pains? (I did not downvote)

Comment: There are tons of php/mysql tutorials out there. You could try and write some code yourself. What you are asking is a complete solution, not "fixing an issue".

Comment: Presumably an employee who was present for 4 days and absent for 0 is "better" than an employee who was present for 6 days and absent for 3? If so, the current solutions that only look at present days are not quite what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
   $query = mysql_query("select name ,`Employee id` as emplyee_id, CONCAT(count(`Employee id`),' Present days') as Attendance
   from Table1 
   where `Attendance` = 'present' group by `Employee id` ");



   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo $row['name']. " - " .$row['emplyee_id']. " - " .$row['Attendance']."</ br>";
 }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab0f2/4)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in view.php on line 11

Comment: here is the code <?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("empl", $con);

  $query = mysql_query("select name ,`Employee id` as emplyee_id, CONCAT(count(`Employee id`)," Present days") as Attendance
   from Table1 
   where `Attendance` = 'present' group by `Employee id` ");



   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo $row['name']. " - " .$row['emplyee_id']. " - " .$row['Attendance']."</ br>";
 }
?>

Comment: you didnt use exactly my query code .

Comment: i was try for demo its working or not then i will edit in to my code thats why i use your query

Comment: sorry it was mistake with double quotes , i changed it to single quotes , try now my query

Comment: I should not use this `CONCAT(count(Employee id),' Present days')` why not solve this in the code instate of in the query...

Answer (score 1):

**SQL**

```
SELECT name, employeeID count(userID) as datesAttend FROM Attendance GROUP BY name
```

**PHP (mysql class method, just an example)**

```
/* mysql_query example ( use beter db class ) */

$best = 0;
$bestEmployee = '';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT Name, EmployeeID, count(EmployeeID) as datesAttend FROM Attendance GROUP BY EmployeeID");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo $row['Name']. " " .$row['EmployeeID']. " " .$row['datesAttend'];
  if($row['datesAttend'] > $best) {
   $best = $row['datesAttend'];
   $bestEmployee = $row['EmployeeID'];
  }
}

echo $bestEmployee ." is employee of the year!!!";
throw PartyForEmployee();
```

Example:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d282/2/0

Comment: It would be better to group the results by `Employee ID`, rather than the name. Just incase there are two or more employee's with the same name.

Comment: Good point @AdrianCrepaz made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

A query like this:

```
select employeeId, count(employeid) as num from table_name group by attendence limit 1
```

will give you the best worker's id. And you can edit the table by inserting it to the proper location. Also could you explain your question a little more?

```
//DB_HOST etc. are db connection constants
$dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$data = mysql_query('your query') or die(mysql_error());
// A COUNT query will always return 1 row
// Use fetch_assoc it's easier to use
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$bestId = $row['employeeId'];
$bestDayNumber = $row['num'];
```

Comment: how can i use this in to php code i want also php code

Comment: I think you should make up your mind. Pick either `mysqli` or `mysql` and stick to it...

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the best employee:

```
select Name, "Employee id", count(*) 
from table_name 
where Attendance = "present" 
group by Name 
order by count(*) desc 
limit 1;
```

The "group by" clause means you want a separate result for each employee.  The "where" clause makes sure you don't count days when they were absent.  The "order by" clause puts the employees with the most days present first.  The "limit" clause just gets the first one, since you only want the best.

Comment: can u give ma php code how can i use in to php

Comment: @user2260431: you should be willing to web-search for "how to use it in PHP" yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query..

```
SELECT *, COUNT(employee_id) AS cnt, CASE WHEN employee_id = (SELECT employee_id FROM employees
WHERE 1 GROUP BY  employee_id ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id) DESC LIMIT 0 , 1)   THEN 'Best' 
ELSE 'Not' END AS avl
FROM  `employees`
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Change table name and field name according to your need